# node_view does not show the comments box

Tags: views, nodes

*I am using* `node_view(node_load($nid), "full")` *and I* `print(render())` *the result in a template. But the content of the node is appearing but not the comments nor the comments form. How can I display them ?*

Comment: If you have changed the content type to allow for commenting, it does not back-propagate to existing nodes. So, check to see the individual comment settings on each of nodes that it does not appear on to make sure they are indeed enabled.

Comment: It is allowed. When I visit /node/[nid] I see the comments and the comment box. It dissapears when using node_view. I cleared cache. It happens in all nodes. It is another problem.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to use the [node_show()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.module/function/node_show/7) function instead; it outputs the node as well as its accompany comment thread and comment form. node_show() relies on node_view() to print the node itself, but also calls comment module's code to build the rest.

One good rule of thumb for tracking down these scenarios is to visit the api.drupal.org site, look up the function that you're using to output a portion of the information you need, and look at the functions that *also* call it in Drupal core.

Comment: It loades only the content again. I know it is being used because the title is "Revision...".

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to get it work. With:

```
render( comment_node_page_additions(node_load($nid));
```

Incredible. Thanks for your help anyway, it headed me in the right direction.